# jquery data() method not always working?

Tags: jquery, image, height, width

i'm having really bad problems in creating reliable jquery code that resizes images to the width of it's parent div. sometimes it's working sometimes just not. at first i thougth IE is just bugging me, however there are times that safari, firefox or chrome are not firing my method as well.

```
    $(".post-body img").each(function() {  
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
    });
```

i'm saving the width and height width the data method in my window.load - function.

after that, i'm calling the setimgwidth() function.

```
function setimgwidth() {
    var bw = $('.post-body').width();
    $(".post-body img").each(function() {   
            if (bw < $(this).data('width')) {
                $(this).attr( 'width', Math.round(bw) );
                //calculate ratio height
                var newHeight = (bw / $(this).data('width')) * $(this).data('height');
                $(this).attr( 'height', Math.round(newHeight) );
            }
    });
}
```

so i'm checking if the parent div is smaller than the image inside of it, the image should resize to the width of the parent div.

I just cannot find out, why this method is not ALWAYS working. Sometimes the images resize, sometimes not.

do you see anything weird? anything you would do better?
some other methods?

thank you

edit:

```
jQuery(function($){//document ready

    $(window).load(function(){

        //Save the original image width
        $(".post-body p img, .post-body .wp-caption img").each(function() {  
            $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
            $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        });

        //window resize event
        $(window).resize(function() {
            setimgwidth();
        });

        //set image width inside of .post-body
        function setimgwidth() {
            $(".post-body p img, .post-body .wp-caption img").each(function() {
                console.debug($(this).data('width'));
                console.debug($(this).data('height'));
            });
        }

        //call image-resize functions onload
        setimgwidth();

    });

});//document ready
```

console always tells me that the width and height of the image is 0.

Comment: is `setimgwidth` also being called in `window.load`?

Comment: yes! if i use console.debug($(this).data('width')); sometimes it's 0 sometimes it's the real size. i just don't get why it's not always working. i wonder if there is a better way to what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one place you are using `$(this).attr('width');`, whereas in another you are using `$(this).width()`. Try `.width()` and `.height()`, which I believe are the ones you should be using, in both places:

```
$(".post-body img").each(function() {  
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
});

$(".post-body img").each(function() {   
        if (bw < $(this).data('width')) {
            $(this).width(Math.round(bw));
            //calculate ratio height
            var newHeight = (bw / $(this).data('width')) * $(this).data('height');
            $(this).height(Math.round(newHeight));            
        }
});
```

Also (perhaps not relevant) shouldn't you be setting the data width and height attributes for each image after you change their dimensions?

```
$(".post-body img").each(function() {   
        if (bw < $(this).data('width')) {
            $(this).width(Math.round(bw));
            //calculate ratio height
            var newHeight = (bw / $(this).data('width')) * $(this).data('height');
            $(this).height(Math.round(newHeight));
            $(this).data("width", Math.round(bw));
            $(this).data("height", newHeight);
        }
});
```

And finally, I hope you are storing the image dimensions onload as @Emmett suggested in his comment:

```
$(".post-body img").load(function() {  
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
});
```

Remember that `width()` and `height()` return the actual content width and height, regardless of CSS properties, so those values should only be captured once the content/images or whatever have been fully loaded.

Comment: the weird thing is that console.debut always tells me that ($this.data.('widht') and 'height' 0 is. But that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

***Code-review** (This is not an answer)*

I re-factored your code. I believe it is considerably more readable now.

```
function setImgWidth() {
    var b = $(".post-body");
    var bw = b.width();

    b.find("img").each(function() {
            var t = $(this);
            var tw = t.data("width");
            var th = t.data("height");

            if ( bw < tw ) {
                t
                    .width(Math.round(bw))
                    .height(Math.round((bw / tw) * th));
            }
    });
}
```